# How can i tell if a file is lzop or lzma?

Tags: lzma, lzo

I have files that are compressed with both lzop and lzma and without proper extensions to their filename. e.g. "filename" instead of filename.lzo or filename.lzma

how can i tell if they are compressed in their respective format?

Answer (score 0):

Mines compressed with Lzop v1.01 contains as 2nd, 3rd and 4th bytes "LZO",
those compresed by mean of 7Zip/Lzma contains "7z" as first two bytes,
just a clue and my 2 cents.